# How to disable info box in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Quick question, I seem to be unable to guess the name of this "info box" properly, so google won't find me the right solution to disable this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its called Intellisense in VSCode terms and you can configure it accordingly with these settings in you `settings.json` files

Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings

Search and click on "Edit in settings.json"

```
    // Controls if quick suggestions should show up or not while typing
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false,

    // Enables parameter hints
    "editor.parameterHints": false,

    // Controls if suggestions should automatically show up when typing trigger characters
    "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
```

If you want to access these features even after disabling these, you can use the keyboard shortcuts.

`CTRL+SPACE` - Trigger Suggestions

`CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE` - Trigger Parameter Hitns